# Indentation not being followed on TypeScript/TSX

Tags: indentation

I have problem with the indentation in JSX/TSX files, I'm not sure how to describe it but the thing is that it does not follow the indentation on the file, please take a look the gif below:

[image: Failure to follow indentation]

After pressing `enter`, the line goes to the left ignoring the current level of indentation. I tried pressing `tab` but nothing happens.

I noticed that using `rjsx-mode` (major mode, not `-minor`) fixes the problem but then I lose all the nice functionality from TSX and LSP. Maybe I need to change my approach to this so if you could also point me in the right direction to setup emacs for React with TypeScript, I would be really grateful.

Btw, this is the top of `describe-mode`:

`Minor modes enabled in this buffer: Company Display-Line-Numbers
Eglot--Managed Eglot-Inlay-Hints Eldoc Flymake Font-Lock Js2 Rjsx
Tree-Sitter

The major mode is TypeScript TSX mode...`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `rjsx-mode` as major mode, the `Tree-sitter` code parser is not used anymore (becoming useless). That's why it fixes the indentation issue. But, not sure `rjsx-mode` pretty highlights Typescript specific code.

I do not know which version of `Emacs` you have, but under `Emacs 29.1` with last version of [Tree-sitter tsx language](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter-typescript), I do not have this issue, but no sure to have tested with a similar JSX structure (not easy, based on your gif).

If you can run `Emacs 29+`, you could also be interested in using [jtsx](https://github.com/llemaitre19/jtsx). It provides `jtsx-tsx-mode` and `jtsx-jsx-mode` major modes which use built-in `Tree-sitter` package and come with some fixes and additional features.